# WordPress front page sections

Tags: wordpress, frontpage

I'm creating a new theme for WordPress, need help to display the content "about" and "contact". I need a professional / readable form, not simply want to paste the HTML code directly in index.php.

[image]

I thank you in advance for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are asking, but I have used [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) in an enterprise environment before and it really does the job well as far as portability between pages and customization options go.

I would advise you to test-drive and try the demo before you commit to buying it so you can know if it fits your project scope.

EDIT: This needs to be moved to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/